# How can I cover all the exceptions from various injected services by writing only one unit test?

Tags: c#, code-coverage, xunit

I'm testing a method that is of structure like this:

```cs
public IActionResult MethodBeingTest(RequestModel req){
   try{
      var value1=_serviceA.Method1();
      var value2=_serviceB.Method2();
      var value3=_serviceC.Method3();

      return CreateResponse(value1+value2+value3);
   }catch(Exception ex){
      return CreateBadResponse("Something bad happened.");
   }
}
```

In order to check if any of the injected services throws so that a `BadResponse` is created, I wrote a test like this:

```cs
[Fact]
public void MethodBeingTest_ServicesThrow_ReturnBadResponse(){
   Exception ex=new("Something bad happened.");
   mockServiceA.Setup(x=>x.Method1()).Throws(ex);
   mockServiceB.Setup(x=>x.Method2()).Throws(ex);
   mockServiceC.Setup(x=>x.Method3()).Throws(ex);

   //...
}
```

Obviously, my test will in fact only detect that `BadResponse` is created when `Method1()` throws but will never tell what if `Method2()` and `Method3()` throw. However, I don't want to write three testing methods for this as it looks foolishly redundant.

Is there a way to do that? Is it possible to write a theory test that only `Setup()` the method to be tested each time?

Please help.

Comment: To be honest i think testing all methods themselves is redundant. You just want to make sure that if ANY method throws an exception then a bad response is returned. 
That would be a different story if you needed to catch specific types of exceptions and handle them differently

Comment: You got the point! Actually I may have oversimplified the code I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could accomplish this is by using `Theory` and `InlineData` to introduce some parameters to the test that determine when the mocked methods throw an exception. If you went that route, it might look something like this:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(true, false, false)]
[InlineData(false, true, false)]
[InlineData(false, false, true)]
public void MethodBeingTest_ServicesThrow_ReturnBadResponse(
   bool serviceAShouldThrow,
   bool serviceBShouldThrow,
   bool serviceCShouldThrow)
{
   Exception ex=new("Something bad happened.");

   if (serviceAShouldThrow) {    
      mockServiceA.Setup(x=>x.Method1()).Throws(ex);
   }

   if (serviceBShouldThrow) {
      mockServiceB.Setup(x=>x.Method2()).Throws(ex);
   }

   if (serviceCShouldThrow) {
      mockServiceC.Setup(x=>x.Method3()).Throws(ex);
   }

   //...
}
```

Comment: Sure. You can definitely extend this concept further - parameterizing your tests and having lots of variations with `InlineData` is a really powerful tool.